# How do I change the background color in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, colors

The background color on some web pages is light gray. This makes it difficult for me to read the page. I want to change the background color to white. I use the Chrome browser. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an option for setting the background colour explicitly in the current theme. However, you could try a different [theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes?hl=en-GB) which would override a whole bunch of settings.

However, it could be that the websites in question have set a background colour themselves which overrides the default of the browser.

Firefox (for example) has as option that lets you set the background colour and then not let individual websites override that value. So it might be you have to use a different browser for these sites.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know about the Firefox option. Want to know if Chrome has a similar one.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small extension to change text/background color for chrome browser.

With mouse dragging, page color will change in real-time.
So you can adjust and adjust ... until you feel satisfied.

Here is the online installation link from chrome web store.

[Babu Color](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/babu-color/dkabogmdcebincpnhjkblipnceehimch)

It is pretty easy to use... Try several times and you will find out
how to use it.

[Video Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HNi5nH1lgU)

Comment: Does this also work like IDE's do to stop your eyes hurting?